# How do i access href attributes of <a> to compare urls as per requriement?

Tags: javascript

```
<style>
.aaaa{
background:red;
}
</style>

<div class="subnav_catg">
<article id="anything" class="catg_list"><a class="catg_photo" href="http://www.xyz.com/1"> <img src="http://www.xyz.com/11.jpg"> </a> <hgroup>
        <h1 class="catg_title">
            Make it</h1>
        </hgroup> </article>
<article id="anything" class="catg_list"><a class="catg_photo" href="http://www.xyz.com/2"> <img src="http://www.xyz.com/65.jpg"> </a> <hgroup>
        <h1 class="catg_title">
            Chocolate</h1>
        </hgroup> </article>
<article id="anything" class="catg_list"><a class="catg_photo" href="http://www.xyz.com/3"> <img src="http://www.xyz.com/79.jpg"> </a> <hgroup>
        <h1 class="catg_title">
            Divine</h1>
        </hgroup> </article>
</div>

<script>
var url_string = document.URL;
var mainarticle = document.querySelectorAll('.subnav_catg');
for (var i = 0; i <= mainarticle.length; i++) {
    var current_article = mainarticle[i];
    if (url_string == current_article.firstChild.attributes[href]) {
        var theParagraph = getElementsByClassName('catg_list');
        theParagraph.setAttribute('id', 'aaaa');
    }
}
</script>
```

In above code i am comparing current url with 'a' tag which is in each article if it matches than replace id from 'anything' to 'aaaa'
but i am not getting. so Whats wrong?

Comment: Mind posting this on a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

`current_article.firstChild.attributes[href]` should surely be `current_article.firstChild.attributes['href']` or `current_article.firstChild.attributes.href`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

1. In the `for` loop use `i < mainarticle.length` rather than `i <= mainarticle.length`. Your current `for` loop as defined will take you out of the boundaries of `mainarticle`.
2. While we're looking at the `for` loop... I would suggest declaring a variable to store `mainarticle.length` so you're not doing a lookup of the `length` property with each iteration: `for (var i = 0, l = mainarticle.length; i < l; i++)`.
3. `href` is a property of the anchor DOM element so just reference it as such: `current_article.firstChild.attributes.href` instead of `current_article.firstChild.attributes[href]`.
4. `var theParagraph = getElementsByClassName('catg_list');` grabs *every* DOM element with that class name so `theParagraph` is actually a node collection of three elements.
5. Anyway, you already have the element you're looking for. You assigned it to the variable `current_article` so just use `current_article.id = 'aaaa';`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> for (var i = 0; i <= mainarticle.length; i++) {
>     var current_article = mainarticle[i];
>     if (url_string == current_article.firstChild.attributes[href]) {
```

The attributes property of an element returns a [NamedNodeMap](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922). The properties are accessible by name, but you must use the right syntax. To get the attribute named *href* using square bracket notation:

```
  current_article.firstChild.attributes['href'];
```

To use dot notation (allowed as href is a valid identifier), which might be more convenient:

```
  current_article.firstChild.attributes.href;
```

but that just returns the attribute node. If you want the actual value:

```
  current_article.firstChild.attributes.href.value;
```

But all that seems like a lot of work, why not just access the property directly to get the value:

```
  current_article.firstChild.href;

>         var theParagraph = getElementsByClassName('catg_list');
```

[getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) is a method of the document and element interfaces (first standardised in HTML5 but now moved to DOM 4 core), so:

```
          var theParagraph = document.getElementsByClassName('catg_list');
```

.

```
>         theParagraph.setAttribute('id', 'aaaa');
```

But getElementsByClassName returns a live [HTML Collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#htmlcollection) (a type of [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177)), and they don't have a *setAttribute* method. You can access the members by index though. If you expect only one element to be returned, it will be at index 0 and you can set its id property using:

```
    theParagraph[0].id = 'aaa';
```

#### Edit

Access href property:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="
   return confirm('Do you really want to go to ' + this.href + '?')
">Google</a>
```

Comment: i tried all to access href attribute but i am not able to do that. can you help with demo.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
current_article.firstChild.attributes.href.value or
current_article.firstChild.attributes.href.nodeName or
current_article.firstChild.attributes.href.name
```

(there are more)

instead of

```
current_article.firstChild.attributes.href
```

only